# Editing multiple tag data in XML via batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

```
    (for /F "delims=" %%a in (Settings.xml) do (
       set "line1=%%a"
       set "newLine1=!line1:DefaultLatitude>=!"
       if "!newLine1!" neq "!line1!" (
          set "newLine1=<DefaultLocation>%newLoc%</DefaultLocation>"
       )
       echo !newLine1!
    )) > newFile.xml
    copy newFile.xml Settings.xml
```

I'm using this to modify the value of DefaultLocation in Settings.xml, how can I expand this to be able to modify multiple tags within the same function?

At the moment I'm just copy and pasting it and it seems inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an inner loop with `"from|to"` values (`|` looks good and is unlikely to be used in your values):

```dos
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (Settings.xml) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    for %%b in (
        "DefaultLatitude>|<DefaultLocation>%newLoc%</DefaultLocation>"
        "herp>|<foo>%foo%</foo>"
        "derp>|<bar>%bar%</bar>"
    ) do for /f "delims=| tokens=1,2" %%c in (%%b) do (
        if "!line:%%c=!" neq "!line!" set "line=%%d"
    )
    echo.!line!
)) > newFile.xml
```

- `echo.` is used to correctly print empty lines

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!